# How can we limit the box with drawRect() to Square in onTouch event

Tags: android

I want to draw a resizable box. It should be a square as I move my finger.

I am using the following code for my android app, for re-sizable box drawing with onTouch Event.

http://chintanrathod.com/resizable-rectangle-overlay-on-touch-in-android/

This code exactly meets my requirement with only one exception. It is not limited square. I want to limit it to square as I move my finger. I have tried to limit the calculations by calculating the delta but haven't got succeed.

```
public class DrawBoxView extends View {

    Point[] points = new Point[4];
    private OnBoxTouchListener onBoxTouchListener;
    Point startMovePoint;
    /**
     * point1 and point 3 are of same group and same as point 2 and point4
     */
    int groupId = -1;
    private ArrayList<ColorBall2> colorballs = new ArrayList<ColorBall2>();
    // array that holds the balls
    private int balID = 0;
    // variable to know what ball is being dragged
    Paint paint;
    Canvas canvas;

    public DrawBoxView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events
        canvas = new Canvas();
    }

    public DrawBoxView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public DrawBoxView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events
        canvas = new Canvas();
    }

    // the method that draws the balls
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (points[0] == null) {
            //initialize rectangle.
            points[0] = new Point();
            points[0].x = 50;
            points[0].y = 20;

            points[1] = new Point();
            points[1].x = 200;
            points[1].y = 20;

            points[2] = new Point();
            points[2].x = 200;
            points[2].y = 170;

            points[3] = new Point();
            points[3].x = 50;
            points[3].y = 170;

            balID = 2;
            groupId = 1;
            // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
            int count = 0;
            for (Point pt : points) {
                colorballs.add(new ColorBall2(getContext(), R.drawable.gray_circle, pt,count++));
            }
        }

        if(points[3]==null) //point4 null when user did not touch and move on screen.
            return;

/**My modification to calculate delta**/
        int diffWidth = Math.abs(colorballs.get(1).getX() - colorballs.get(0).getX());
        int diffHeight = Math.abs(colorballs.get(1).getY() - colorballs.get(0).getY());

/**End of My modification**/

        int left, top, right, bottom;

        left = points[0].x;
        top = points[0].y;
        right = points[0].x;
        bottom = points[0].y;



        for (int i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
            left =      left    > points[i].x ? points[i].x         : left;

            top =       top     > points[i].y ? points[i].y         : top;

            int x_delta = Math.abs(points[0].x - points[1].x);

            right =     right   < points[i].x ? points[i].x         : right;

            bottom =    bottom  < points[i].y ? points[i].y         : bottom;

/**My modification to calculate delta**/
int y_delta = Math.abs(points[1].y - points[2].y);

            if(x_delta != y_delta)
            {
                int bottom_delta = Math.abs(points[1].y - bottom);
                if(bottom_delta < y_delta)
                {
                    bottom = bottom + bottom_delta;
                }
                else if(bottom_delta > y_delta)
                {

                }
            }
        }
/**end of my code**/
        Log.e("Left", String.valueOf(left));
        Log.e("top", String.valueOf(top));

        Log.e("right", String.valueOf(right));
        Log.e("bottom", String.valueOf(bottom));

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        //draw stroke
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        canvas.drawRect(
                left + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                top + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                right + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                bottom + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);
        //fill the rectangle
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_color_red_transparent));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        canvas.drawRect(
                left + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                top + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                right + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                bottom + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);

        //draw the corners
        BitmapDrawable bitmap = new BitmapDrawable();
        // draw the balls on the canvas
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setTextSize(18);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        for (int i =0; i < colorballs.size(); i ++) {
            ColorBall2 ball = colorballs.get(i);
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),
                    paint);

            //canvas.drawText("" + (i+1), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), paint);
        }
    }

    // events when touching the screen
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();

        int X = (int) event.getX();
        int Y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (eventaction) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on
                // a ball
                if (points[0] == null) {
                    //initialize rectangle.
                    points[0] = new Point();
                    points[0].x = X;
                    points[0].y = Y;

                    points[1] = new Point();
                    points[1].x = X;
                    points[1].y = Y + 30;

                    points[2] = new Point();
                    points[2].x = X + 30;
                    points[2].y = Y + 30;

                    points[3] = new Point();
                    points[3].x = X +30;
                    points[3].y = Y;

                    balID = 2;
                    groupId = 1;
                    // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
                    int count = 0;
                    for (Point pt : points) {
                        colorballs.add(new ColorBall2(getContext(), R.drawable.gray_circle, pt,count++));
                    }
                } else {
                    //resize rectangle
                    balID = -1;
                    startMovePoint = new Point(X,Y);
                    groupId = -1;
                    for (int i = colorballs.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                        ColorBall2 ball = colorballs.get(i);
                        // check if inside the bounds of the ball (circle)
                        // get the center for the ball
                        int centerX = ball.getX() + ball.getWidthOfBall();
                        int centerY = ball.getY() + ball.getHeightOfBall();
                        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                        // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the
                        // ball
                        double radCircle = Math
                                .sqrt((double) (((centerX - X) * (centerX - X)) + (centerY - Y)
                                        * (centerY - Y)));

                        if (radCircle < ball.getWidthOfBall()) {

                            balID = ball.getID();
                            if (balID == 1 || balID == 3) {
                                groupId = 2;
                            } else {
                                groupId = 1;
                            }
                            invalidate();
                            break;
                        }
                        invalidate();
                    }
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // touch drag with the ball


                if (balID > -1) {
                    // move the balls the same as the finger
                    colorballs.get(balID).setX(X);
                    colorballs.get(balID).setY(Y);

                    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);


                    /*if (groupId == 1) {
                        colorballs.get(1).setX(colorballs.get(0).getX());
                        colorballs.get(1).setY(colorballs.get(2).getY());
                        colorballs.get(3).setX(colorballs.get(2).getX());
                        colorballs.get(3).setY(colorballs.get(0).getY());
                    } else {
                        colorballs.get(0).setX(colorballs.get(1).getX());
                        colorballs.get(0).setY(colorballs.get(3).getY());
                        colorballs.get(2).setX(colorballs.get(3).getX());
                        colorballs.get(2).setY(colorballs.get(1).getY());
                    }
*/

                    if (groupId == 1) {


                        colorballs.get(1).setX(colorballs.get(0).getX());
                        colorballs.get(1).setY(colorballs.get(2).getY());
                        colorballs.get(3).setX(colorballs.get(2).getX());
                        colorballs.get(3).setY(colorballs.get(0).getY());
                    } else {
                        colorballs.get(0).setX(colorballs.get(1).getX());
                        colorballs.get(0).setY(colorballs.get(3).getY());
                        colorballs.get(2).setX(colorballs.get(3).getX());
                        colorballs.get(2).setY(colorballs.get(1).getY());
                    }

                    invalidate();
                }else{
                    if (startMovePoint!=null) {
                        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                        int diffX = X - startMovePoint.x;
                        int diffY = Y - startMovePoint.y;
                        startMovePoint.x = X;
                        startMovePoint.y = Y;
                        colorballs.get(0).addX(diffX);
                        colorballs.get(1).addX(diffX);
                        colorballs.get(2).addX(diffX);
                        colorballs.get(3).addX(diffX);

                        colorballs.get(0).addY(diffY);
                        colorballs.get(1).addY(diffY);
                        colorballs.get(2).addY(diffY);
                        colorballs.get(3).addY(diffY);
                        if(groupId==1)
                            canvas.drawRect(points[0].x, points[2].y, points[2].x, points[0].y,
                                    paint);
                        else
                            canvas.drawRect(points[1].x, points[3].y, points[3].x, points[1].y,
                                    paint);
                        invalidate();
                    }
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // touch drop - just do things here after dropping

                break;
        }
        // redraw the canvas
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    public OnBoxTouchListener getOnBoxTouchListener() {
        return onBoxTouchListener;
    }

    public void setOnBoxTouchListener(OnBoxTouchListener onBoxTouchListener) {
        this.onBoxTouchListener = onBoxTouchListener;
    }

    public Rect shade_region_between_points() {
        if (points[0] == null && points[2] == null) {
            return new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (points[0] == null) {
            return new Rect(0, points[2].y, points[2].x, 0);
        }
        else if (points[2] == null) {
            return new Rect(points[0].x, 0, 0, points[0].y);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Rect(points[0].x, points[2].y, points[2].x, points[0].y);
        }
    }

    public Point[] getPoints()
    {
        return points;
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the formulas with TOUCH_MOVE and onDraw events by calculating the delta X, but I haven't got any success. Anyone can guide to modify this code will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to relate to the code in the link you described to make it simple:

From what I understand, the balls in organized in these indexes:

```
0               3

1               2
```

To keep this simple, I will refer to each ball as their index.

Before setting X and Y of selected Ball,  calculate Delta:

```
 if (balID > -1) {
              float deltaX = colorballs.get(ballID).getX() - X;
              float deltaY = colorballs.get(ballID).getY() - Y;
              colorballs.get(balID).setX(X);
              colorballs.get(balID).setY(Y);
```

Now we use delta when we update balls coordinates:

```
  if(balID == 0){       //Top Left ball
        colorballs.get(1).setX(colorballs.get(balID).getX());
        colorballs.get(2).setX(colorballs.get(2).getX() + deltaY);
        colorballs.get(3).setY(colorballs.get(ballID).getY);
        colorballs.get(3).setX(colorballs.get(2).getX());
    }
```

If we move ball 0, this happens:

```
                                Dragging 0 up
                            ^           ^
                            |deltaY     |   moves alongside 0 
                            0           3  -->  Expand by deltaY

                            1           2  -->  Expand by deltaY

                                Dragging 0 right        
                                deltaX     
                            0   -->     3
                                        ^  
                                        |       Reduce Y by delta X
                            1   -->     2  -->  Expand by deltaY
```

Since moving down will result in negative delta, it will be handled automatically.
This is the basic concept,
You can do the same to rest of the balls as well by simply replacing the indexes in above snippet.